Receive the connection id in API Gateway WebSocket on connect
I have created a WebSocket API in AWS API Gateway. When I connect to it from the browser, I want the client to immediately receive the connection id over the websocket. Is is possible to achieve this only with API Gateway with Mock integration, without adding a lambda function?
I tried to add a $default route and enable two-way communication, but still don't receive a message on connect. I also tried to add an integration request on the $connect route, but still no success.

I don't think so - without a backend service like Lambda, API Gateway alone cannot dynamically send the connection ID back upon connection due to the lack of access to $context variables directly in the Mock integration. AFAIK minimal Lambda function would be needed to retrieve the connection ID and send it back

@SamarPrakash i managed to do it with just Mock integration, but not on connect. After I connect, I send a message to a route, and it returns the connection Id. The route has to be enabled for two-way communication, to add integration request with template {"statusCode": 200} and to add integration response template {"connectionId" : "$context.connectionId"} .

Great, thanks for sharing the info !!
